# How do I understand when to use the phrase 'mad props'?

Tags: idioms, word-usage, phrase-usage, context

In [Legally Blond the musical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legally_Blonde_(musical)) [they use the phrase](https://www.letras.com/legally-blonde/1042553/):

> MARGOT: Dear Elle, He's a lucky guy. I'm like gonna cry, I got tears coming out of my nose!
>
> Mad Props! He's the campus catch, You're a perfect match,
> Cause you both got such great taste in clothes, Of course he will propose!

I see it used in a congratulatory sense, *"mad props to you for doing X"*.

My intuition tells me that this is about *"giving someone their propers"* - but that makes no sense in this context to me. (As in, I don't have enough information to categorise that.) I'd never heard that used in a sentence before - and it smells of a social obligation.

My question is: **How do I understand when to use the phrase 'mad props'?**

Comment: I have a few times seen "props" used in a sense that implies a meaning of "praise" or "congratulations".  I'm thinking it's been mostly in the show business realm.  [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=props&utm_source=search-action) calls it "proper recognition", "proper respect", or "propers".  (Note that "propers" is not idiomatic in the US, though apparently it is used in rap circles.)

Comment: You're almost there:  "Mad props to you for making the perfect match with the campus catch."

Comment: whenever you feel **X** is praiseworthy, you can use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is don't use it. I think people who use this phrase come across as "try hards". To me they sound like they are trying hard to look cool by imitating a culture they are not part of.

If you insist on using it, you could consider softening it by dropping the "mad" prefix. E.g.

"Props to Andy for winning the hack-a-thon"

Comment: I wouldn't be ***too*** down on the usage, bearing in mind [it's even got its own entry in Merriam-Webster now.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mad%20props#:~:text=Definition%20of%20mad%20props,the%20performers%20deserve%20mad%20props.) Most "ephemeral slang" doesn't get that far.